# Javascript acessing script on other page

Tags: javascript, html

I have a question about acessing the JavaScript on a other page.
I have two frames, one is auto-reloading and the other one is playing a video.

The codes are below:

videoshow.html

```
 <html>
      <head>
       <script type="text/javascript">
          window.onload = setupRefresh;

          function setupRefresh() {
              setInterval("refreshFrame();", 1000);
          }
          function refreshFrame() {
             parent.right_frame.location.reload();
          }
      </script>
      </head>
      <frameset id="cntfrm" cols="*,100">
        <frame name="left_frame" src="videoplayer.html" frameborder="0" />
        <frame  name="right_frame" src="refresh.html" />
      </frameset>
    </html>
```

videoplayer.html

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="java.js"></script>



</head>

<body bgcolor="#00000">

<div align="center">
<video id="myVideo" width="*" height="*" autoplay> <!-- controls ->se quiserem com as cenas a aparecer -->
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <object   data="movie.mp4" width="*" height="*">
  </object> 

</video>

</div>

<div align="center">
<font color="white" id="fastforward" size="4"></font>
<br>
<button type="button" onclick="vid_play_pause()">Play/Pause</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

refresh.html

```
<html>

<body bgcolor="#00000">
<button  onclick="javascript:parent.left_frame.vid_play_pause">Play/Pause</button>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to click Play/Pause on refresh.html and stop the video at the videoplayer.html is this possible? Don't worry about the javascript because it works on the videoplayer.html, I just need to know how to call the function on refresh.

Answer (score 0):

Try on refresh.html

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function playPause(){
window.parent.parentPlayPause();
}
</script>
```

Then on videoshow.html

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function parentPlayPause(){
document.getElementById('left_frame').contentWindow.vid_play_pause();
}
</script>
```

Comment: can you send me the link of the page? Also you need to add the id on left frame: <frame id="left_frame" name="left_frame" src="videoplayer.html" frameborder="0" /> and on refresh <button  onclick="playPause()">Play/Pause</button>

Comment: the page is offline and i did put the id on the frame and i did put onclick="playPause()" :\ i can't understand why it doesnt work..

Comment: It's working fine on me. I created 3 pages with your code and i manage to call a function in videoplayer from refresh. Your problem might be this: vid_play_pause(), create a function to do an alert or something on videoplayer and you'll see that it works.